# buy Now Button in product hover setting in theme

Tags: wordpress, button, wordpress-theming

I would like to add a 'Buy Now' button to product hover. like the customer doesn't have to click and view the product but he or she can click the buy now button and redirected to the checkout page immediately.

Currently, the page looks like this.
[image: Current hover setting]

and I want something like this
[image]

I researched a lot and found some plugins. They are paid. I also checked the codes but I am not a php developer so I didn't quite understand the code. like where to go and how to edit etc etc.

The theme I am using is Kapee. kindly let me know if you guys know the answer. Thanks in advance :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Added the code in your theme functions.php file you will see a button after add to the cart button

```html
// define the woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button callback 

function action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button(  ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
    $custom_url = home_url('/checkout/');
    ?>
    <a class="btn button" href="<?php echo esc_url($custom_url);?>">
        <?php
            echo esc_html__('Buy Now', 'textdomain');
        ?>
    </a>
    <?php
}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 10, 0 );
```

Also You can use any third-party plugin for this see the plugin link

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-add-to-cart-button/